# Edge Vertices Node: How does it work?

Tags: edges, geometry-nodes

Here is the description of the node in the manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/edge_vertices.html

Here is the node, and another mentioned in the same description:
[image]

I was wondering if anyone had a **practical example** of the use of these nodes, so that I could understand what the manual is describing.

Comment: tbh...these are two questions....because they are two nodes...

Comment: I appreciate the extra work, and it clarifies what they were trying to say in the manual. Thank you for explaining both nodes with practical examples.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with "field at index" you can "ask" your attribute (e.g. a position) for a position at another index. e.g. so you could connect 2 points like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

for the edge vertices nodes you can use this kind of node setup:

[image]

and you will get a smoothing of your vertices:

[image]

Credits to: https://youtu.be/s9_Rnu_XIPA